# stopword removal in python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of sentences as follows

```
pylist=['This is an apple', 'This is an orange', 'The pineapple is yellow','A grape is red']
```

If I define a stopwords list such as

```
stopwords=['This', 'is', 'an', 'The']
```

Is there a way for me to apply this to the entire list such that my output is

```
pylist=['apple','orange','pineapple is yellow','A grape is red']
```

PS: I tried to use `apply` with a function defined to remove stopwords like `[removewords(x) for x in pylist]` but wasn't successful (plus not sure if this is the most efficient way).
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to add 'a' to the list of stopwords because 'an' is there as well. Then you should fix your expected result 'pylist'  to be ['apple','orange','pineapple yellow','grape red'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested list comprehension, and define `stopwords` as a `set` to reduce the lookup complexity to `O(1)`:

```
pylist=['This is an apple', 'This is an orange', 'The pineapple is yellow',
        'A grape is red']
stopwords = set(['This', 'is', 'an', 'The'])

[' '.join([w for w in s.split() if w not in stopwords]) for s in pylist]
# ['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple yellow', 'A grape red']
```

Note however, that for a more general approach you can use the `stopwords` from [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html)'s english corpus:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_w = set(stopwords.words('english'))

[' '.join([w for w in s.split() if w.lower() not in stop_w]) for s in pylist]
# ['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple yellow', 'grape red']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your output is not what you really want. The stopwords 'is' is still included.

My attempt would be the following:

```py
pylist = ['This is an apple', 'This is an orange', 'The pineapple is yellow', 'A grape is red']
stopwords = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'The']

stopwords = set(w.lower() for w in stopwords)


def remove_words(s, stopwords):
    s_split = s.split()
    s_filtered = [w for w in s_split if not w.lower() in stopwords]
    return " ".join(s_filtered)


result = [remove_words(x, stopwords) for x in pylist]
```

with the `result` being

```py
['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple yellow', 'A grape red']
```

To get a reasonable efficient search (look-up in a set takes of course constant time), I stored the lower-case form of the stop words in a set. Usually removal of stop words should be case insensitive.

*Side-note:* It is very often helpful or even necessary to remove stop words. But please be aware of the fact that there are cases where stop word-removal is not advisable: https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-avoid-removing-stopwords-aa7a353d2a52

*Update:* When you are really sure that you need to get rid of all possible stop words, make sure you do not miss any - take yatu's advise: Have a look at [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html). Especially if in the next year you might be faced with the problem of having to add Spanish palabra de paradas, French mot d'arrêt and German Stopp-Wörter.